# Where all List values are equal to column List

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

Hello I have a problem and i cant solve it for 3 days. I've red many posts here and in google, but I cant find the solution.

In db I have column "Gener" - nvarchar(350) which contains for example this:

```
row 1: 1,4,32,11
row 2: 32,11
row 3: 1
row 4: 4,56,1,23
row 5: 4
```

From checkboxlist I check this values: 1,4 which add to

```
List<string> gnr = new List<string>();
```

**The result which I want is row 1 and row 4.**

I've made (take from stackoverflow) code which result is row 3 and row 4:

```
 var result = from m in db.Movies
              where gnr.Contains(m.Gener)
              select m;
```

And code which result is row 1, row 3, row 4 and row 5:

```
foreach (string term in gnr)
{
    var trb = db.movies.Where(o => o.Gener.Contains(term));
}
```

With Ole DB I can make it, but with LINQ I can't here is the code there:

```
List<string> Gener = new List<string>();
Gener = Action,Comedy

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
string lastItem = Gener[Gener.Count - 1];

// Here I made string Which I'll add to cmd string
foreach (string safePrime in Gener)
{
    if (safePrime != lastItem)
    {
        builder.Append("((gener LIKE '%" + safePrime + "%')) AND").Append(" ");
    }
    else
    {
        builder.Append("((gener LIKE '%" + safePrime + "%')) ORDER By ID DESC").Append(" ");
    }
}

string dbSelect = builder.ToString();

//The result from loop
dbSelect = "((GenerLIKE '%Action%')) AND ((GenerLIKE '%Comedy%')) ORDER By ID"
//Add dbSelect to exist cmd
Cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE " + dbSelect;
```

And the result here is what I want with LINQ, select all movies that are Action and Comedy
Thanks for the time you red this, I'll be very thankful for some help. Sorry for my english I hope it is readable.

Comment: Probably you mean **geNDer**.

Comment: Why do you have spaces between number and comma in some places and in other places not?

Comment: I dont have space in DB my format text mistake when I write this... Sorry

Answer (score 1):

`String.Split` does not work with Entity Framework, so you can move splitting Gener column value in memory:

```
var result = from m in db.movies.ToList()
             let movieGnr = m.Gener.Replace(" ", "").Split(',')
             where m.Gener != null && !gnr.Except(movieGnr).Any()
             select m;
```

Returns rows 1 and 4.

UPDATE: As stated above, this solution will load all movies data into memory. What I suggest to you is changing DB structure - create MovieGeners table, which will contain Geners for each movie. And add navigation property to Movie which will contain list of Geners. This solution will allow to move all query to the database side.

```
int[] gnr;
var result = from m in db.movies.Include("Geners")                 
             where gnr.All(g => m.Geners.Any(x => x.Id == g))
             select m;
```

Comment: I don't know how to thank you very much, that works perfect, that was what I searched for. I hope your Answer and my question help to somebody!

Comment: @Momchilov no problem. Just one advice - create table `MovieGenres` which will hold movie and genre ids. Then you will be able to do search on server side without loading entities into memory. And yes, you can accept answer :)

Comment: I'll take your advice, thanks a lot :) Now I'm moving on next step.

Comment: @Momchilov again, there is no way for you to speed up Linq solution, until you change your database. Because Split cannot be translated to SQL by EF Linq provider. Either change database (create many-to-many table), or use plain SQL.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I downvoted your answer, because taking all records from base is not good solution at all.

Comment: @karaxuna have your read my first comment on this answer? Don't you see I pointed to that issue?

Comment: Hi, I didnt want to disturb you again, so I try my self to do this, and I think Find a solution.
First: in foreach take all results that contain 1 and 4, so the rows become smaller amount
Second: the code that you gave me I use it for making .ToList() and it will be faster, but still it is not what I want

I've tried many to many table but I cant find out to take just records that contain both 1 and 4.

With ole db is not the best solution, but it is faster then linq in this situation.

Comment: Sorry About spaces, its my mistake in DB I dont Have it. I'll edit it!

Comment: I think this solution was not so bad after all (because of evil database structure :) ). I would remove downvote, but too much time has passed.

Comment: @karaxuna I've made and edit with advise about changing database structure :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky for edit, I don't have such property .Include(). Is there any way to take [row 1] and [row 4] if I use many to many table. This structure was one of first that I've made, but I've stopped because the codes that I write gave result just [row 3] and [row 5]. I've google it but didn't find anything that can help me.

Comment: @Momchilov `Include` is available in EF. It pre-loads entities for navigation properties.

Answer (score 0):

Below used query would returns row 1 and row 4 data.We need to use where clause and check the row data length. row1 and row 4 data length is 9.This query would work.

```
   var result= db.Movies.Where(mv => mv.Gener.Length > 8).Select(mv => mv.Gener);
```